# Примеры REST API

Tags: php, веб-служба, rest

Я PHP программист и хочу научиться пользоваться RESTful API.

Не создавать REST приложения, а именно обращаться к REST сервисам и получать от них ответ.

Я раньше думал, что Google Maps API, Facebook API или поисковая система Sphinx построены по принципам REST, но вот почитал документации и у меня сложилось впечатление что данные сервисы имеют API далеко не RESTful.

Поэтому прошу, подскажите примеры API основанные на архитектуре REST с хорошей документацией.

Comment: У Twitter есть REST
[https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public]

и у JIRA
[https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis]